# Kotlin short literal pre/postfix?

Tags: kotlin

The following code throws an error that == cannot be applied between int and short.

```
if(shortVal == 3)
```

Does Kotlin have a way to denote that a numeric literal is a short, something like `3S`?

Comment: No, you have to use _3.toShort()_.

Comment: Or _shortval.toInt()_ of course.

Comment: @lukas.j `shortval.toInt()` will only work if you want to compare. There are many other places where short literals are used. And the way the question is worded Google will bring **everyone** who needs a short literal for **any** reason here.

Comment: @Martin I do not understand any of your three sentences. 1) Why should _shortval.toInt()_ not work when doing anything else but comparing? 2) There are zero places where short literals are used, as there is no syntax for Short literals in Kotlin. 3) ???

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no functionality like that in the standard library, as far as I know.
But you're still free to implement a functionality like that on your own, e.g. using Kotlin's extension properties.

```kotlin
val Int.s: Short
    get() = toShort()

val i: Int = 3
val s: Short = 3.s
```

Comment: I wonder why this error exists in the first place. In C#, `short a = 3; if( a== 3){}` does not throw any error. Is this because the Kotlin compiler is not smart?

Comment: It's more that Kotlin (and Rust, Swift, Go) are trying to avoid having complicated rules for *programmers*.

Silent narrowing coercions throw out data; so many teams prohibit it via linters that language designers consider it an anti-feature.

C#, Java or C++ already had coercions before generics, and all of them have nasty corner cases as a result.

Kotlin could take a page from modern C++: give literal numbers their own fake type that's downcast to a int/short/long/etc.

Comment: @Ben But we are talking literal values here. Even Ada, the pinnacle of high integrity software, will shorten literals. Ada won't shorten anything else but literals. (and yes, Ada also uses a fake type called universal integer to do it).

Comment: @Martin The earlier comment asked if the compiler is simply unable to do it, and my argument was that it's a deliberate design decision.

I think the universal literal approach is entirely reasonable, but it does make literals are subtly different from names. I don't think people have trouble with that complexity, but I can see how the Kotlin team might disagree.

Answer (score 2):

You could also create an infix function instead of `==`.
I called it `eq`

```
infix fun Short.eq(i: Int): Boolean = this == i.toShort()
```

And you can use it like this

```
if(shortVal eq 3)
```